# PayPal Rails 4.1 doesnt redirect well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.1.

I can pay but when I want to redirect it redirects to sanbox.paypal..../return_url and I want to redirect to return_url. I want to execute an action after paying by PayPal.

How can I do that? Thnx!!
This is my code:

```
def paypal_url(return_url)
values = {
    :business => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXx',
    :cmd => '_cart',
    :upload => 1,
    :return => 'return_url',
    :invoice => id,
    :currency_code => tour.currency,
}
values.merge!({
    "amount_1" => tour.price,
    "item_name_1" => tour.title,
    "item_number_1" => tour.id,
    "quantity_1" => '1'
})
"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you've a simple mistake. Change it to:

```
def paypal_url(return_url)
values = {
    :business => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXx',
    :cmd => '_cart',
    :upload => 1,
    :return => return_url,
    :invoice => id,
    :currency_code => tour.currency,
}
values.merge!({
    "amount_1" => tour.price,
    "item_name_1" => tour.title,
    "item_number_1" => tour.id,
    "quantity_1" => '1'
})
"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
end
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! but I still have the same problem. It tries to redirect to sandbox.paypal.com/return_url but as this web page doesn't exist it redirects to sandbox.paypal.com/home

Comment: What argument are you using calling `paypal_url`?

Comment: This is the function call: redirect_to @booking.paypal_url(tour_booking_path(@tour, @booking)). It redirects to sandbox.paypal.com/tours/1/bookings/6 but it should redirect to http://localhost:3000/tours/1/bookings/6 Thank you so much!!

Comment: Use tour_booking_url(@tour, @booking). _path is only relative, you'll need the full URL by using _url.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works!! and more important you explained me why it didn't work, so now I understand what the problem was :) Thank you again!

Comment: Great, please accept this answer, or just close the question again to help others :)